# How to disbale pepflashplayer.dll in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to disable pepflashplayer.dll(this file is responsible for playing flash content on web pages), programmatically (through java script or some other means), but not getting any way to do that.

Instead what I found that we can go to chrome://plugins url and then by clicking on disable link for this dll we can achieve this, but I do not want this manual way of doing this.

Please suggest some way.

Comment: As far as pure JavaScript is concerned, it is out of range of its power. Perhaps an extension could assist you, but the user would have to install that. However, once installed your site could communicate with the extension and enable or disable, but I have no clue of where to point you to. Why do you need this in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for info, but this flash player is given by chrome browsers which has couple of issues, so we want our users to use adobe flash player instead. We dont want each of our user to go and manually do it. so that is the reason while installing our component we want to disable it. Anyways can you tell me the way to automatically install the extensions like mozilla. I have manifest.json file for my extension , now when the first time when chrome will run it should pick that manifest and ask the user to add it. How can we do this in chrome?

Comment: I can't help you a lot on this topic, I don't do a lot of browser-specific coding. This is what Google came up with: [also on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472240/automate-google-chrome-extension-installation) and [Chromium Project](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/pre-installed-extensions). Maybe something's in there that helps you out. I guess your best bet is to use an external crx package.

Comment: Just a side note: disabling the pepflashplayer is also the resolution to the "HBO GO cannot play this show at this time. Please try again later. [Code D-1006]" error on HBOGo.com !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple!

1) In Chrome go to: `chrome://plugins`

2) disable: Adobe Flash Player (maybe the first option)

3) and now install the flashplayer of your OS version (they'll use your default flash player version)

Comment: Actually I was looking for some automated solution, some script which if we execute it will change the plugins.  But Anyways this solution is also OK for me as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/types.html API, for enabling and disabling installed types

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I did and it's working so far.

In Chrome's address bar type: `chrome:plugins`

There you'll find the Adobe Flash Player plugins, disable the pep dll first, then search for the location of the pep dll file, go there and not only delete the dll file but also delete the folder named PepperFlash.

Restart your computer and thats it. That worked for me.